# Moving in 2-d array of rectangle cells with arrows

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

i need help on a maze game that i'm trying to build. I know there is a lot written on that topic, but i can't get it right. So, on the problem - i want the user to escape from the maze with arrow keys. I build the maze from 2-d array of rectangle cells from the tutorial [here](http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/mazetut/index.htm).
And that is the method.

```
public static Grid DFS(Grid grid)
    {
        Stack<Cell> cellStack = new Stack<Cell>();
        int totalCells = grid.Cells.GetLength(0) * grid.Cells.GetLength(1);

        Cell currentCell = grid.Cells[0, 0];
        currentCell.IsVisited = true;
        grid.VisitedCells = 1;

        while (grid.VisitedCells < totalCells)
        {
            List<Cell> neighbours = GetNeighbours(grid, currentCell);
            if (neighbours.Count > 0)
            {
                Cell newCell = GetRandomNeighbour(neighbours);
                CrushWall(currentCell, newCell);
                newCell.IsVisited = true;
                cellStack.Push(currentCell);
                currentCell = newCell;
                grid.VisitedCells++;
            }

            else
            {
                currentCell = cellStack.Pop();
            }
        }

        return grid;
    }
```

Then i add it on a panel in the main form:

```
 private void mediumToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        panel1.Controls.Clear();
        Grid grid = new Grid(30, 30);
        panel1.Size = grid.Size;
        grid.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        panel1.Controls.Add(grid);
        maze = Maze.DFS(grid);
    }
```

So far so good. Now i want to escape from the maze. Start point is Cell[0,0] and the goal is at the last Cell, let's say Cell[30,30]. Here is my attempt for that. It's not finished yet and covers just when we go right and down. What it happens is that i go just one cell right or down and that's it. Noting more! Please tell me where i'm wrong!

```
void frmMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < maze.Rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < maze.Columns; j++)
            {
                maze.Cells[i, j].IsVisited = false;
            }
        }

        Cell currentCell = maze.Cells[0, 0];

        if (currentCell == maze.Cells[maze.Rows - 1, maze.Columns - 1])
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Well Done! You made it!");
        }

        else
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Right:
                   currentCell = Maze.GoRight(maze, currentCell);
                   currentCell.IsOnPath = true;
                   maze.Invalidate(); 
                   break;

                case Keys.Down:
                    currentCell = Maze.GoDown(maze, currentCell);
                    currentCell.IsOnPath = true;
                    maze.Invalidate();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the going right for example:

```
public static Cell GoRight(Grid maze, Cell currentCell)
    {
        List<Cell> neighbours = GetMazeNeighbours(maze, currentCell);
        Cell rightNeighbour = new Cell();

        if (neighbours.Any())
        {
            foreach (var item in neighbours)
            {
                if (item.LeftWall == 1)
                {
                    rightNeighbour = item;
                }
            }
        }
        return rightNeighbour;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two potential problems I can see straight away. Firstly, most seriously, you're initialising currentCell to the cell at [0,0] every time you press a key. So, every time a key is pressed currentCell goes back to [0,0]! That can't be right.

Secondly, you need to break out or return from your foreach as soon as you assign rightNeighbour, or any other cells in the list of neighbours that are subsequently found matching the `item.LeftWall == 1` criteria will overwrite the assignment.(Plus it's inefficient to iterate through a list when you've already found what you're looking for).

e.g.

```
        foreach (var item in neighbours)
        {
            if (item.LeftWall == 1)
            {
                rightNeighbour = item;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gareth. I've fixed the problems you pointed and it worked. Well not exactly, because it seems i have some mistakes in logic that gets neighbours and paints the path that the user takes. I'll mark your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Finally i was able to locate the problem and fix it. Here it is on the image:

[image: Maze Sample]

The black cell is the current cell that we`re on. The yellow ones are the neighbours. The problem is that the two neighbours have the same properties. For example:

```
neighbour1.TopWall = 1;
neighbour2.TopWall = 1;
```

This means that the top wall of both neighbours is crushed.
Let`s say i want to go down. In the KeyDown event the condition for going down is true for both of the neighbours, so it is pure luck that the correct neighbour is the first met here:

```
foreach (var item in neighbours)
    {
        if (item.TopWall == 1)
        {
            rightNeighbour = item;
            break;
        }
    }
```

And i solved it like this:

```
if current cell has neighbours
check if bottom cell is not null
if false, check if its top wall is crushed
if true, make bottom cell the current cell
```

I hope this will help to someone! Cheers!